# getResultList() method of StoredProcedureQuery is taking too long

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate

I am having a table in Oracle 19c with around 80000 records. To fetch this data I have a stored procedure. On executing this stored procedure it took around 2-3 minutes to give me all the data. When I am trying to use the same using Spring JPA + Hibernate it is taking around 20 minutes to get the output from getResultList()

Stored Procedure is having parameters like below.

1. IN parameter as string
2. IN parameter as string
3. IN parameter as string to pass some json payload containing few fields
4. OUT parameter as string in json format to give the output response showing success or failure
5. OUT parameter as REF_CURSOR having actual data

In my Java code, I am doing something like below.

```
  @PersistenceContext
  EntityManager entityManager;

  public List<String> executeQuery(BaseRequest request, String queryName) {
    StoredProcedureQuery storedPQ = entityManager.createNamedStoredProcedureQuery(queryName);
    //Setting the input parameters using below method
    setQueryParams(storedPQ, request);
    storedPQ.execute();
    return storedPQ.getResultList();
  }
```

Can anyone please suggest what should I do to fine tune it so that turnaround time comes down to somew

Comment: Contact your DBA to analyze the query execution plan.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to this problem. When I fetch the data via ResultSet then total time comes down to 2 mins.

Basically instead of calling storedPQ.getResultList() I replaced it with something like below.

```
    ResultSet resultSet = (ResultSet) storedPQ.getOutputParameterValue(OUTPUT_REF_CURSOR);
    List<String> resultList = new ArrayList<>();
    resultSet.setFetchSize(100);
    while (resultSet.next()) {
      resultList.add(resultSet.getString(1));
    }
    resultSet.close();
```